# How to add Hprim support to mirth?

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

we are using mirth to receive and serialize HL7 messages, and now we have Hprim also we need to serialize it but mirth don't support by default the Hprim stander, we found [this fourm](https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/issues/browse/MIRTH-2482) to add Hprim to mirth but how can we apply those patches to mirth we are new to mirth, please help.

Comment: This sounds as a project rather than a simple answer. You better hire someone who knows Mirth better than you to help you out.

Comment: @Shamil you are every where, but your comments not helping, and about this can you help you seems to know mirth very well.

Comment: If I would tell you to place those libraries into a /custom-lib folder will that help you a lot? Probably not, because then you will have tons of follow up questions. That's why I mentioned that this looks as a small project rather than just an answer.

Comment: @Shamil - Stop using custom-lib. Recent releases of Mirth Connect added "resource directories". These provide better isolation of custom JARs and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with HPRIM.

I can however say that we have been able to provide extensive support for other data formats and transports using the jar files as a resource (settings > resources), adding a channel dependency (for the resource), and just using the java api's from javascript to accomplish the goals of the project.  Perhaps this is something that could work for you if you have sample code to validate/construct/deconstruct your HPRIM messages.  This would mean you have to code a lot/most of your translates in javascript though.  You would also use channelMaps as your output values instead of the encoded messages etc.

Not necessarily an answer, but it shows one of the ways that Mirth can be extremely flexible and allow you to support various transports/formats without having to patch the original source code or get someone to build you a custom extension.

Frans